# Image Element in SVG File not Showing in FireFox or Illustrator

Tags: svg

I am trying to get an image to display in my .svg file. It currently will show on Chrome but does not show up on Firefox and Adobe Illustrator. I have looked around a lot online and have yet to find a solution to my problem. Any advice?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="963" width="744" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  >
<image xlink:href="images/image.png" height="45" y="10" x="662"  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the image element height and width attributes. These are mandatory in SVG 1.1.

SVG 2 proposes that height and width become optional but that specification is still in progress as are implementations of it. Firefox and Illustrator don't yet implement that SVG 2 feature though they do implement others.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely solved my FireFox issue! For some reason when I open the file in Illustrator, the image doesn't appear on the canvas but it appears off far to the right. Is this a known issue?

Comment: No idea about illustrator, sorry.